# Spark joins performance issue

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to merge historical and incremental data. As part of the incremental data, I'm getting deletes. Below is the case.

- historical data  - 100 records ( 20 columns, id is the key column)
- incremental data - 10 records  ( 20 columns, id is the key column)

Out of the 10 records in incremental data, only 5 will match with historical data.

Now I want 100 records in the final dataframe of which 95 records belong to historical data and 5 records belong to incremental data(wherever id column is match).

Update timestamp field is available in both historical and incremental data.

Below is the approach I tried.

```
    DF1 - Historical  Data
    DF2 - Incremental Delete Dataset
    DF3 = DF1 LEFTANTIJOIN DF2
    DF4 = DF2 INNERJOIN DF1
    DF5 = DF3 UNION DF4
```

However, I observed It has lot of performance issue as I'm running this join on billions of records. Any better way to do this?

Comment: as you you are using df1 and df2 more than once , and you are creating new df4,df3 from them, you could try persisting df1 and df2 and increase their partitions(depends on ur default parellilism and your cluster). you could also look into sort-merge joins that involve sorting before joining for better performance. you could also look into repartitioning(numpartitions, join column) before persisting. this way ur dfs will be distributed on the join columns with more partitions ..

Comment: Mohammad Murtaza Hashmi, I tried caching and re partition, but they didn't helped me.

Comment: Hello, instead of using Join operators, you can use a cogroup combined with a user defined function that filters the two lists generated by the cogroup to obtain the different types of joins, if this answer interests you I will post detailed code of the alternative of join operator using cogroup below.

Comment: What is spark version.? If you are using latest spark version, then go for `delta` format.

Comment: @Ahlam AIS, Could you post the solution please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the approach I did.

```
historical_data.as("a").join(
incr_data.as("b"),
$"a.id" === $"b.id", "full")
.select(historical_data.columns.map(f => expr(s"""case when a.id=b.id then b.${f} else a.${f} end as $f""")): _*)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the cogroup operator combined with a user defined function to construct the different variations of the join. 
Suppose we have these two RDDs as an example :

```
visits = sc.parallelize([("h", "1.2.3.4"), ("a", "3.4.5.6"), ("h","1.3.3.1")] )
pageNames = sc.parallelize([("h", "Home"), ("a", "About"), ("o", "Other")])
cg = visits.cogroup(pageNames).map(lambda x :(x[0], ( list(x[1][0]), list(x[1][1]))))
```

You can implement an inner join as such :

```
innerjoin = cg.flatMap(lambda x: J(x))
```

Where J is defined as such :

```
def J(x):
    j=[]
    k=x[0]
    if x[1][0]!=[] and x[1][1]!=[]:
        for l in x[1][0]:
            for r in x[1][1]:
                j.append((k,(l,r)))
    return j
```

For a right outer join for example you just need to change the J function to an roJ function defined as such :

```
def roJ(x):
    j=[]
    k=x[0]
    if x[1][0]!=[] and x[1][1]!=[]:
        for l in x[1][0]:
            for r in x[1][1]:
                j.append((k,(l,r)))
    elif x[1][1]!=[] :
        for r in x[1][1]:
            j.append((k, (None, r)))
    return j
```

And call it like so :

```
rightouterjoin = cg.flatMap(lambda x: roJ(x))
```

And so on for other types of join you'd wish to implement

Answer (score 0):

Performance issues are not just related to the size of your data. It depends on many other parameters like, the keys you used for partition, your partitioned file sizes and the cluster configuration you are running your job on. I would recommend you to go through the official documentation on Tuning your spark jobs and make necessary changes.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html